# Read opengraph property and use as field title

Tags: 8, rules, meta-tags

I have a simple site that generates an article content in the page. This content is a link preview of the article URL. My goal is when an article is created I want to use metatag property sitename as the author of the post, e.g. `<meta property="og:site_name" content="ABC">`, then the author shall be **ABC**. I actually want to achieve this using Rules. My inital question is how can I programmatically read/access opengraph property from an external link and assign it as user/author of the post?